# Joining lines with POSIX sed

Tags: sed, posix, newlines

I'm trying to join lines with POSIX sed.

With GNU sed (without --posix) this works as intended:

```
$ sed ':a; N; s/\n//; b a' <<< $'a\nb\nc'
abc
```

But if I use --posix I get no output.

Why is this and how can I how can I do it otherwise?

Comment: A POSIX sed prints sed: Label too long: :a; N; s/\n//; b a

Comment: Is the data always read from standard input, or could it be lines in a file on disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a job for `paste`:

```
printf '%s\n' a b c | paste -sd '\0' -
```

(no, that's not joining with NULs, that's joining with no separator as required by POSIX. Some `paste` implementations also support `paste -sd '' -` but that's neither standard nor portable).

Note that except in the busybox implementation, it produces one empty line as output if the input is empty (a historical bug/misfeature unfortunately now engraved in the POSIX specification).

With POSIX `sed`:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}' -e 's/\n//g'
```

Or:

```
sed '
:a
$!{
  N
  ba
}
s/\n//g'
```

The `b`, `:`, and `}` commands cannot be followed by another command. In earlier versions of the POSIX specification, `b a;s/a/b/` would require `b` to  branch to the label called `a;s/a/b/`, in newer versions of the specification, it's now unspecified, to allow the GNU `sed` behaviour. The following command has to be in a subsequent expression or on a separate line.

Also POSIX requires `N` on the last line to exit without printing the pattern space. GNU `sed` only does it in POSIX mode, like when there's a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment or with your `--posix` option which explains why you get no output with `--posix`.

Also note that the minimum size of the pattern space guaranteed by POSIX is 8192 bytes. You can only use that approach portably for very small files. `paste` has no size limitation, and contrary to the `sed` approach doesn't need to load the whole file in memory before printing it.

Another approach is `tr -d '\n'`. However note that contrary to `paste`/`sed`, it produces a non-delimited line on output (outputs `abc` instead of `abc\n` on the example above).

In any case, `<<<` is a `zsh` operator (now supported by a few other shells), and `$'...'` is a ksh93 operator (now supported by most other POSIX-like shells), neither are POSIX `sh` operators (though the latter is likely to be added to the next major revision of the standard), so should not be used in POSIX `sh` scripts.

Comment: @EdMorton, you're right (except for the busybox implementation of `paste` which is not POSIX compliant in this instance)! I hadn't realised that. I'll edit it in.

Comment: A `sed 'H;1h;$!d;g;s/\n//g'` is also POSIX, has no branches (and thus no labels), so it needs no additional `-e` sections (easier to type).

Answer (score 3):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box for any size input file (unless that input file is just 1 massive line of text containing no spaces that can't fit in memory):

```
$ printf '%s\n' a b c | awk -v ORS= '1; END{if (NR) print RS}'
abc
```

Comment: An `awk '{ printf( "%s", $0 ) } END { if (NR) print "" }'` doesn't need to change AWK internal variables.

Comment: Right, either approach is fine. I'd guess that setting ORS to null and letting a normal print happen might be a bit more efficient than calling printf but it'll be a drop in the ocean. Btw they don't hurt but you don't need parens around the `printf` arguments as it's a builtin language construct, not a function.

Comment: You seem to agree, then talk about speed. (1) Coding require choices. The `printf` option is more flexible in the conditions it could be used, has less requirements. (2)Yes, the `ORS=` is faster, twice faster. (3) But, if you do need speed, you may want to try some other utility and walking out of AWK, try `tr -d '\n'` (and code for a newline). It is  about 10 times faster. Is that too far away from your "zone of comfort"?. (4) If the parens are allowed (and indeed they are), then, it is matter of preference. I prefer to clearly mark start and end. (5) Why do you get confused with a function?